# React JS input в который можно вписать только цифры или пустую строку

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, reactjs

Как сделать так чтобы в input можно было вводить только цифры или пустую строку?

Comment: `<input type="number"/>`

Comment: Только цыфры. без e + - 
Что то не понятно написал?

Answer (score 1):

Можно проверять новое значение при записи в стейт:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const onChange = ({target: {value}}) => setValue(prev => /\d+/.test(Number(value)) ? value : prev);
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <input {...{value, onChange}}/>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: хороший код.Только хочу спросить `<input {...{value, onChange}}/>`что делает вот это строка можно обяснить ?

Comment: `<input {...{value, onChange}}/>` тоже самое что и `<input value={value} onChange={onChange}/>`, можно еще `cont params = {value, onChange}; <input {...params} />`;

Comment: ясно спасибо . (1 символ нужен)